# Postgres many-to-many relation: finding rows all having relation to a set of rows from related table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider three tables, let's call them `groups`, `subgroups`, `another_groups` and table `subgroups_another_groups` that is specifying many-to-many relation between `subgroups` and `another_groups`. `subgroups` and `groups` are in one-to-many relation, so `subgroups` has foreign key `group_id`.

How is it possible to select `another_groups` that all of `subgroups` within a `group` have relation to?

Comment: it would be nice to have ddl, some sample data and expected result. preferably build on some db-fiddle or rextester or such

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are speaking of such a setup:

```
CREATE TABLE groups (
   id integer PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE subgroups (
   id integer PRIMARY KEY,
   group_id integer REFERENCES groups NOT NULL
);
CREATE INDEX ON subgroups(group_id);

CREATE TABLE another_groups (
   id integer PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE subgroups_another_groups (
   subgroup_id integer REFERENCES subgroups NOT NULL,
   another_groups_id integer REFERENCES another_groups NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(subgroup_id, another_groups_id)
);
CREATE INDEX ON subgroups_another_groups(another_groups_id);
```

Then you want to know all `another_groups` that are connected to a `groups` via the other two tables except the ones where there is a subgroup that does not have a connection to this `another_groups`, right?

In SQL, that would read:

```
SELECT DISTINCT g.id, a.id
FROM another_groups a
   JOIN subgroups_another_groups sag ON a.id = sag.another_groups_id
   JOIN subgroups s ON sag.subgroup_id = s.id
   JOIN groups g ON s.group_id = g.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS
         (SELECT 1 FROM subgroups s1
          WHERE s1.group_id = g.id
            AND NOT EXISTS
                   (SELECT 1 FROM subgroups_another_groups sag1
                    WHERE sag1.subgroup_id = s1.id
                      AND sag1.another_groups_id = a.id
                   )
         );
```